# Replacement substring in shell input

Tags: bash, shell

I get the set of strings as input in terminal. I need to replace the `".awk"` substring to `".sh"` in each string using **shell** and then output modified string. 
I wrote such script for doing this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
  result=${line/.awk/.sh}
  echo $result
done
```

But it gives me an error: `script-ch.sh: 6: script-ch.sh: Bad substitution`.

**How should I change this simple script to fix error?**

**UPD:** `".awk"` may be inside the string. For example: `"file.awk.old"`.

Comment: But I have this error...

Comment: What version of bash are you running? What distribution? It works fine for me with v4.1.2 on Centos 6.5

Comment: I have v.4.3.11(1)-release on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Wild guess: Use double quotes (i.e., `result="${line/.awk/.sh}"`). I suspect you have a space in the line. Also: Why not simply `sed 's/.awk/.sh'`?

Comment: What inputs are you giving it?

Comment: @Wintermute, no I should use only shell. Thanks for the double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why it works for you and not for me.. might be the input you're giving it. It could have a space in it.

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
  result=$(echo $line | sed 's/\.awk/\.sh/')
  echo $result
done
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Bash, then there is nothing wrong with your substitution. There is no reason to spawn an additional subshell and use a separate utility when bash **substring replacement** was tailor made to do that job:

```
$ fn="myfile.awk.old"; echo "$fn  -->  ${fn/.awk/.sh}"
myfile.awk.old  -->  myfile.sh.old
```

**Note:** if you are substituting `.sh` for `.awk`, then the `.` is unnecessary. A simple `${fn/awk/sh}` will suffice.

I suspect you have some stray DOS character in your original script.

Answer (score 0):

If you run chmod +x script.sh and then run it with ./script.sh, or if you run it with bash script.sh, it should work fine.

Running it with sh script.sh will not work because the hashbang line will be ignored and the script will be interpreted by dash, which does not support that string substitution syntax.